# the Assetbundle from server works when build to .exe, but doesn't work on WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's first time I work with WebGL,
I tried to put my 3d assets on server with AssetBundle,
so people will not have to wait long when open the page,
the Assetbundle from server works when build to .exe, but doesn't work on WebGL
and yes, I'm already set the BuiltTarget to WebGL,
here's my code, please help me what do I miss,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class LoadAssetBundle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string url;
    public string assetName;

    public Vector3 position;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
        StartCoroutine(UnityWebReq());
    }

      IEnumerator UnityWebReq()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

            if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(uwr.error);
            }
            else
            {
                // Get downloaded asset bundle
                AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(uwr);

                     GameObject obj = (GameObject)bundle.LoadAsset(assetName);
                    
                Instantiate(obj, position, Quaternion.identity);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What error does it give

Comment: It works perfectly when I test, but no assets loaded when I built

Comment: So make it debug stuff to screen to check where it gets to and what it does

Comment: thanks for your answer, the error log is "Asset Bundle download is complete, but no data have been received"

Answer (score 1):

#### Different target platforms require different Asset bundles!

In short an AssetBundle build for Standalone(/Editor) will not be compatible with other build target platforms like UWP, mobile, WebGL etc.

You have to explicitly build your AssetBundles for the according target platform.

The fact that as you say your AssetBundles work when building your app to `.exe` (= Standalone) doesn't sound like you are building your AssetBundles for WebGL.

It would help to see how exactly you are building your AssetBundles.

---

In general see e.g. [`BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles.html)

> **Note that bundles built for standalone platforms are not compatible with those built for mobiles and so you may need to produce different versions of a given bundle.** See the BuildTarget section of the [Building AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Building.html) page in the Manual for more information about creating AssetBundles for different platforms.

And from that mentioned section

> You can find a list of the available explicit build targets in the Scripting API Reference for [`BuildTarget`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildTarget.html). **However, if you’d rather not hardcode in your build target, feel free to take advantage of [`EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUserBuildSettings-activeBuildTarget.html) which will automatically find the platform you’re currently setup to build for and build your AssetBundles based on that target.**

Comment: I've already set the TargetPlatflorm to WebGL, when I check an error on the Log, it shows "Asset Bundle download is complete, but no data have been received"

Comment: This is STILL an issue as of February 16, 2022. DO NOT USE ASSET BUNDLES & ADDRESSABLES FOR YOUR WEBGL project!!!!!!!!! We have 5 senior backend devs & 2 senior Unity devs for a CCG project similar to Hearthstone. We've tried everything: deployment tuning, hosting bundles on the same server as the Unity webglbuild, etc.. The only thing that works for sure is to host raw png files somewhere & loading these png url's directly WITHOUT using any stupid bundles. Waisted 3 weeks on this & still couldn't utilise bundles!!!!